# Extending an element in generating set for free abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory, free-abelian-group

Let $G$ be a finitely generated free abelian group and $S$ be a minimal generating set i.e. ${\rm rank}(G)=|S|$. If $w$ is a word in $G$ then when it can be extended in a new minimal generating set for $G$? For example if $S=\{s_{1},s_{2}\}$ then $s^{n}$ can not be extended in a new generating set while $w=s^{3}_{1}s^{2}_{2}$  can. Intuitively, I would argue that we should be able to solve for one of the generators. Is this true?

Comment: What does "be able to solve for one of the generators" mean? Also, because I don't see it: which word $v$ makes $\{s_1^3 s_2^2, v\}$ a generating set for $G$ in your example?

Comment: $v=s_1s_2$ would work I think. Write $u=s_1^3s_2^2$, then $uv^{-2}=s_1$ and $u^{-1}v^3=s_2$.

Comment: Yes, the group is abelian.

Comment: The general idea is that you can think of your potentially-a-basis elements as vectors, and then put them into an $n\times n$ matrix. Then your potentially-a-basis is a basis if and only if this matrix is invertible (as an integer matrix - so its inverse must also only have integer elements). So the question is: can your element correspond to a row in an invertible matrix? If $|n|>1$ then $(n, 0)$ cannot be, while $(3, 2)$ can be. (In the $2\times2$ case, its just about being coprime.)

Comment: So $w$ can be extended if we can find $n-1$ words s.t the determinant of the matrix is $\pm 1$?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word "abelian"! Kindly disregard my comments :)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk : Then ... delete them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, there is some linear algebra going on under the hood. That is maybe a hint that we should view this problem geometrically. To that end, I'll be calling elements of this group "vectors", and thinking of them as living in some integer lattice of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed, these kinds of questions arise very naturally in the [geometry of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers).

We say a set of vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_i \}$ is **primitive** exactly when it can be extended to a basis of the lattice. So in this problem we are interested in knowing when $\{ w \}$ is primitive.

If we write $w = g_1^{n_1} g_2^{n_2} \cdots g_k^{n_k}$ in terms of the "natural" basis $\{ g_1, \ldots, g_k \}$, there turns out to be a nice combinatorial description of primitivity:

> $w = g_1^{n_1} g_2^{n_2} \cdots g_k^{n_k}$ is primitive if and only if $\text{gcd}(n_1, \ldots, n_k) = 1$.

A nice computational proof can be found as Theorem $2.1$ in Magliveras, van Trung, and Wei's "Primitive Sets in a Lattice" (see [here](http://brain.math.fau.edu/spyros/spyros/prints/eucLat.pdf)).

This turns out to be related to the comment about finding a matrix whose determinant is $\pm 1$. Indeed, the proof in the above article works by cleverly using [bezout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) to take a (row) vector $w = (n_1, \ldots, n_k)$ and find $k-1$ new (row) vectors $v_2, \ldots, v_k$ so that when we assemble these vectors into a matrix, we find

$$
\text{det} \begin{pmatrix} - w - \\ - v_2 - \\ \vdots \\ - v_k -\end{pmatrix} = \text{gcd}(n_1, \ldots, n_k)
$$

When $\text{gcd}(n_1, \ldots, n_k) = 1$ this matrix has determinant $1$, and thus is invertible as an integer matrix. But this is exactly what it means for your rows to be a basis. The linked article is nice because it shows you what the other basis elements are too.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful :)